# Obtaining some 4.0 functions on a 2.3 phone through rooting?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, updates, calendar

I'm thinking of maybe rooting my phone, for various reasons. But one of the main ones is that I find the current version of Calendar, amongst others, that I have, very lacking. And I'm almost sure the version that comes with Ice Cream Sandwich or later is better. It just has to, seeing all the "what the heck?" things there are in the one I have.

(There's also the fact I need to free my super small phone memory as much as possible, which I'm not allowed to, but this is not what I want to ask about.)

To be clear, I know for sure that my device cannot run full later versions of Android. Clearly, unless you can use an SD card as an extension block of RAM and processor AND install the OS on it, I doubt I can do this. My phone is way too basic.

However, I would like to know if there's a way, through rooting my phone, to get some features of Android 4.0 and up. Such as a better calendar with more features, or the ability to put contacts in groups, for example.

I did look at some third-party calendar software reviews, but none of them seemed to beat the original up-to-date one. Every review seemed to point out things like "calendar app XYZ is great, but X function isn't very compatible with Google Calendar", or "XYZ Google Calendar function doesn't work on it yet", for example.

My phone's specs should be:

- Samsung Galaxy Q (SGH-T589W)
- Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread
- Processor: 600MHz Qualcomm MSM7227 (if indeed it's the same as the Gravity Smart, because information on the Galaxy Q is rare)
- Internal storage: 152 MB, some of which I think is taken up by the OS or useless stock software, because I can't ever seem to free it
- RAM: 279 MB
- SD card: 2 GB

Comment: If it's mainly the calendar issue: have you checked the playstore for alternatives? There are plenty, even for "small phones". Take e.g. a look at [aCalendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.withouthat.acalendar), which is pretty nice and runs from 2.1 upwards.

Comment: @Izzy: I haven't tested any, but I've read a lot of comparisons and reviews, and seen a lot of screenshots, but they all seem to have those saddening "buts".

Comment: You will always find "buts", nothing's perfect. What I recommended you sits on top of the pre-installed calendar and adds some useful things. And it's small (~500k -- compared to > 3M for the "big flag ships" like Jorte), and it's free. Give it a try on your own, you alwas can delete it if you don't like it -- all your appointments are stored in the original Google calendar, aCalendar is just a frontend to its database. So you won't lose anything.

Comment: @Izzy all rightie, I will. If it's good, it'll solve one issue, for starters. :p

Comment: Piece by piece :) Good luck! And before it gets lengthy here: You can always meet us in chat. (Almost) no off-topic there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No!

That would cause the handset to boot-loop or cause F/C (Force Close) as Ice Cream Sandwich and later, their apps are relying on the v4.x framework.

By bringing it across to Gingerbread could spell disaster and "weird" issues with the handset.

However, bringing across Gingerbread 2.3.x apps across to Ice Cream Sandwich should work, (***Paradox ahead...***) as ICS upwards would have compatibility layer within their framework for running apps that target below ICS! Hope this part makes sense!

Comment: Are there any workarounds? For example, a custom OS that is compatible with some ICS features but has lower technical requirements? Anything? I made a mistake with this awful phone, but given my limited budget, I'd like to tough it out for as long as possible before looking into a more capable one.

Comment: No workarounds! Either look to roll your own ROM with ICS bits back-ported into Gingerbread or look for a custom ICS ROM for your device. FYI - Zte Blade has identical chipset and there's ICS/JB ROM available, just to show that the capability is there by a developer to port it.

Comment: Read this [XDA Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1215631) someone is bound to have achieved a custom ROM.

Comment: Rolling a ROM? What do you mean? Anyway, I ran a long and painful search (I'm awful at searching), and all I found that was interesting-ish was a pre-rooted, pre-unbloated minimalist ROM based on Froyo. This would mean I would literally be downgrading. >_> Sigh. ---Oh, hadn't seen your latest message. I'll take a look.

Comment: Rolling a ROM, means to create your own ROM based off the AOSP source project and build it targetting your device in question, but from reading the XDA thread, it seems there's no love for that device and thus, not interested in modding the handset...

Comment: Oh, all right. Sigh, I wish people were more drawn to fixing what's broken. Poor phone. Geez, they won't even base their ROM on Gingerbread. oo'

Comment: There is the source code available on [Samsung](http://opensource.samsung.com/) for that SGH-T589W alright, maybe with that combined with ICS 4.0.4 source might get somewhere...

Comment: Yeah well. I can barely "develop" PHP, Javascript and HTML. I seriously don't think there's anything I can do with that file, myself. :c

Comment: @Ariane ICS really needs at least 512 MB of RAM, so even if you could build it, it wouldn't run very well or at all. It's time for a new phone.

Comment: @Michael Weeeeell. I'm poor and this -is- a new phone to begin with. More, like, it's time to suck it up and endure. :p

Answer (score 1):

As other said, You just can not. Because, every new version of android comes with its' new feature written within its' package (which we know as firmware) So, if you want to have those there is no way. But, Still, you can have some taste of newer version of android on your old one by replacing your stock application with 3rd party application. In some cases, those applications are way better then the stock one. For example you can use a 3rd party dialer and sms app replacing the stock one. How to? Well off-course you have to be rooted. Then use any app that can uninstall system app and make any 3rd party app as system app. In my case I depend on Link2sd to do this job.

This is the only way you can get the flavor of newly release features on your old stock firmware (android version).

Hope that helps.